# web3.js Contract returning null instead of an array

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, arrays

Simple contract:

```
contract ex {
   address[] users;
   function addUser() public {
        users.push(msg.sender);
   }

   function returnUsers() constant returns (address[]) {
       return users;
   }
}
```

In web3js I have the contract instance exInstance:

```
var abi = { /* some ABI */ };
var exInstance = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(someaddress);

function getUsers(){
   let users = exInstance.returnUsers.call();
}
```

And the result is that users is a null. 
Tried async:

```
function getUsers(){
   exInstance.returnUsers.call(function(error, users)
      /// some actions
}
```

But still `null`.

Am I doing something wrong or I just should iterate it in web3js and in contract just use something like `returnUsers(uint i) constant returns (address) { return users[i]; }` ?

Comment: Is an up to date version of your contract deployed?

Comment: oh,u r right, updated the contract but forgot to update the abi.. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to return dynamically sized arrays from external transactions or calls. An external call/transaction is initiated by something outside of the contract code running in the EVM. ([Source](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#can-you-return-an-array-or-a-string-from-a-solidity-function-call))

> **Can you return an array or a string from a solidity function call?**
>
> Yes. See [array_receiver_and_returner.sol](https://github.com/fivedogit/solidity-baby-steps/blob/master/contracts/60_array_receiver_and_returner.sol).
>
> What is problematic, though, is returning any variably-sized data (e.g. a variably-sized array like `uint[]`) from a fuction called from within Solidity. This is a limitation of the EVM and will be solved with the next protocol update.
>
> Returning variably-sized data as part of an external transaction or call is fine.

I'm not sure what is wrong with your code. It works for me in [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/).

Comment: In the remix, it works fine but `string[] memory` returns `null` in js if we are using web3